# What is the difference between embedded and integrated system?

Tags: embedded

An embedded system is a combination between computer hardware,computer software and electronics. For me, examples of embedded systems are `microcontrollers`, `DSPs`,`FPGAs`. I view `SoCs` also as embedded systems.

However, I recently found out that at many universities there are research teams who work on the so-called `Integrated systems`. There must be some difference between an `embedded` and an `Integrated system` but I can't figure it out. Can you please explain me the difference between those two notions?

Comment: there is no governing body that creates and enforces these terms.  they are for the most part subject to interpretation by the individual or company.  Some companies will use one term for various reasons, marketing, engineering, to fit into some specification or industry, etc.   Dont get worked up about the words.    Like the Feynman quote about bird names.  ends with  the difference between knowing the name of something and knowing something.    So dont worry about the names, figure out what these research teams are actually doing, not by title of the project by by content or results

Comment: Even your definition of embedded system is debatable, and IMO incorrect. You have described a system then listed components as examples; they are not embedded systems, merely components that may occur in an embedded system.

Comment: Yes, your definition of embedded system is incorrect (it is a computer system that is embedded in some other hardware, with the purpose of controlling that hardware to perform specific functionality), and what is meant by "Integrated System" is totally unclear, as you don't provide any references where you saw the term.